# opencv - Detect and optimize shapes

Tags: android, opencv

I have a challenge where I have to implement a sample apps on Android. This app allows user draw some shapes on the screen (by finger) and then optimize it to vertex based shapes. I am thinking about Opencv but I don't know what function/feature can help me detect a shape and optimize it. I need some hints or recommendations.

Update: User can draw any type of shapes such as: Circle, ellipse, rectangle, line, curve, polygon, ... So I think it should have an general algorithm for all kind of shapes.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you will be dealing with onTouch events, there could be two approaches: 1) construct a polygon out of the touch lines and see what you can do from there; 2) something with Gestures. I'm not sure if opencv has been ported to android and if it's easily built for the target or not :)